# Ignore element based on SQL Result

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a master SSIS package that runs multiple other SSIS packages based on a queue of job run requests stored in Sql Server.

See [image: This is my package]

The general idea is that I check the queue to see if there is an active request for that package, and if there is, execute the package for a specified date range. After all the packages have run, I picked up all the files generated, rename them/move them to a new folder, update the date range, and then run the packages again for the new date range.

The problem I is that this master package is an 'all or nothing' sort of thing. If any of the child packages don't have a run request, the entire loop fails due to the execute Sql task(P1, P2, etc.) not returning a job run request. I tried changing these execute sql tasks to return a dummy value 'NoRequest' to get around this, and then set an expression on the arrows to check against this. This does filter out packages that don't have job run requests, but the issue now is that the final 3 nodes after all the package executions don't execute if **all** the previous nodes execute due to the connections.

Not sure how to get around this, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you need to change the precedence constraints of all the arrows leading to *Edit File Names for Current Fiscal Week* node to be able to always run the last 3 nodes.

- Right click on those green arrows and click *Edit* to open *Precedence Constraint Editor*
- Select `Logical OR. One constraint must evaluate to True` option in Multiple constraints box.

The arrows leading up to *Edit File Names for Current Fiscal Week* node would now be dotted green.

Answer (score 0):

A possible way to to this is to use, instead of a flag,  a number and you set each process with a specific number (ex. 1;2;4;8..etc) You keep a resultant for the process which have executated from that doesn't. At the end you just need to check that value against a rule you could specify. I hope that helps.